# Gamma function for $0 < n < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function

The gamma function is defined by : $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$ and it says this function is defined on : $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ whereas this definition of the gamma function is of course not defined when $0 < n <1$ ?

Comment: use the functional equation $ \Gamma (s) \Gamma (1-s) = \frac{\pi}{sin(\pi s)} $

Comment: you cannot use factorial if your number is a  non-integer

Comment: The gamma function is **not** defined as $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$. That's just a property it has

Comment: The $\Gamma$ function can be defined as the only function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ fulfilling $\Gamma(1)=1, \Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$ and having a convex logarithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem

Answer (score 4):

The gamma function only satisfies $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for positive integers.

For non-integer numbers you must go back to the actual definition of the gamma function, which is $$\Gamma(x)=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$$ If you evaluate this for $x\in\Bbb Z^+$, you will get the previous result with $(n-1)!$, but for non-integer positive (or negative) real numbers you must use this integral.

Comment: "...for non-integer positive real numbers..." and for non-integer negative real numbers too!

Comment: Ah yes, I was focusing more on how the questioner mentioned $0<x<1$, but yes, that too. Edited to include this comment :)